# Having trouble implementing a javascript tracking function

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm working on a site for a local business. They included a javascript file which tracks where the user comes from and changes phone numbers, banners, and hidden form fields for campaign tracking.
My problem is that I just can't get it to work.

here is the js in question.

```
    var myContactNum  = "";
    var myBannerImage = "";
    var myFriendlyCampaignName ="";
    var campaignInfoSource="";

    var utm_source = "";        

    function campaignInformationLookup(campaignName) {
        switch(campaignName) {

            case "fbgen" :
                myFriendlyCampaignName = "Facebook - Generic Campaign";
                myContactNum = "1-888-980-8550";
                myBannerImage = "http://www.eyetechlasik.com/images/stories/website_header_lasik_8550.jpg";
                utm_source = campaignName;
                break;

            case "drkadambi" :
                myFriendlyCampaignName = "Reputation - Dr. K";
                myContactNum = "1-888-980-8551";
                myBannerImage = "http://www.eyetechlasik.com/images/stories/website_header_lasik_8551.jpg";
                utm_source = campaignName;
                break;
            case "lbv" :
                myFriendlyCampaignName = "Reputation - LBV";
                myContactNum = "1-888-980-8552";
                myBannerImage = "http://www.eyetechlasik.com/images/stories/website_header_lasik_8552.jpg";
                utm_source = campaignName;
                break;

            case "googlesearch":
                myFriendlyCampaignName = "Google Ad - Search Results";
                myContactNum = "1-888-980-8554";
                myBannerImage = "http://www.eyetechlasik.com/images/stories/website_header_lasik_8554.jpg";
                utm_source = campaignName;
                break;

            case "default":
                myFriendlyCampaignName = "Organic - Reached Site without Ad";
                myContactNum = "1-866-808-3937";
                myBannerImage = "http://www.eyetechlasik.com/images/stories/website_header_lasik.jpg";
                utm_source = "default";             
                break;
            default:
                myFriendlyCampaignName = "Organic - Reached Site without Ad";
                myContactNum = "1-866-808-3937";
                myBannerImage = "http://www.eyetechlasik.com/images/stories/website_header_lasik.jpg";
                utm_source = "default"; 
        }
        return utm_source;
    }       


    function getQueryString(name) {
        var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
        return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    }

    function myCampaign() {
        var eyeTechCampaign = getCookie("eyeTechCampaign");

        if(eyeTechCampaign == null || eyeTechCampaign == "" || eyeTechCampaign == 'undefined') {
            myCampaignFromURL = getQueryString("utm_campaign");
            theCampaign = campaignInformationLookup(myCampaignFromURL);
            setCookie("eyeTechCampaign",myCampaignFromURL,180);
            campaignInfoSource = "URL";
        }
        else {              
            theCampaign = eyeTechCampaign;
            campaignInfoSource = "Cookie";
            theSource = campaignInformationLookup(theCampaign);
            //update the cookie to expire 180 days from now, essentially refreshing the campaign
            setCookie("eyeTechCampaign",theCampaign,180);

        }   
        displayContactInfo();   
    }

    function getCookie(c_name) {
        var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
        for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++) {
            x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
            y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
            x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
            if (x==c_name) {
                return unescape(y);
            }
        }
    }

    function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays) {
        var exdate=new Date();
        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
        var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
        document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
    }

    function destroyCookie() {
        //Debug purposes only
        setCookie("eyeTechCampaign",0,-1)
    }

    function displayContactInfo() {

        document.getElementById('headerBanner').src = myBannerImage;
        document.getElementById('footerPhoneNum').innerHTML = myContactNum;

        //Only for the contact us page
        if(document.getElementById('contactUsPhoneNum') !='undefined') {
            document.getElementById('contactUsPhoneNum').innerHTML = myContactNum;
        }

        document.getElementById('OnlineCampaignSource').value = myFriendlyCampaignName;


    }
```

if I jsut try to do something simple like document.write(myContactNum) i get nothing. If i put in my own value for myContactNum ex..

```
  var myContactNum = "1-800-555-5555";
```

I will get that value. Which leads me to believe the function itsself is doing nothing. I've tried calling the function at different parts in the code and still nothing. Any advice?

Comment: can you include the html as well

Comment: Have you looked for any javascript errors in the developers tools? Also, you could write out the values to the console, just before the line "return utm_source".  That way you could see if the function was being called, and if it were executing correctly.

Comment: I uploaded a test version http://www.aaronjakab.com/testeyetech/ the area in question is jsut above "book an appointment" in the header. It should be displaying a number.

Comment: no javascript errors in dev tools.